# Can we use NFC technology to send messages (NDEF) across Android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, nfc, nfc-p2p, open-nfc

I am new to NFC technology, I saw many documentation which are supported to exchange message with in android using nfc tag or android beam.

I wanted to know can we exchange NDEF message from android to iPhone?

Comment: As far as I know, with iOS you can only READ NFC tags, here is a 10 minute video which explain all you need in the iPhone https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/718/